# Finite $T_0$ space

Tags: general-topology

Show that a finite $T_0$ space has an isolated point, i.e, a point $x$ such that {$x$} is open.
I tried to prove it this way, assume no singleton is open $\implies$ ${x}^\circ$= $\varnothing$ $\implies$ $x^c$ is dense for all $x$ in $X$. But I can not do anything after this.

Comment: For each $x$, let $U_x$ be the smallest open set containing $x$. Choose an $x_0$ such that $U_{x_0}$ has the smallest number of elements among the $U_x$. Suppose $U_{x_0} \neq \{x_0\}$. Derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a relation $\leq $ on your set $X$ as follows: $x\leq y$ iff every open set which contains $y$ also contains $x$. This is obviously reflexive and transitive, and it is anti-symmetric precisely because the space is $T_0$. We thus have a partial order on $X$.

Since $X$ is finite (and non-empty! otherwise what you want to prove is false :-) ), it has minimal elements. Each of them has the property you want.

Comment: One needs to know that a non-empty finite partially ordered set $X$ has minimal elements: suppose it doesn't and let $x_1$ be any point. Since $x_1$ is not minimal,there exists an $x_2$ such that $x_2\lneq x_1$. $x_2$ is also not minimal so there is an $x_3$ such that $x_3\lneq x_2$ and so on... This is impossible if $X$ is finite.

Comment: Every non-empty finite partially ordered set is inductively ordered. Zorn does the rest ;)

Comment: Very helpful solution. How do we go about thinking like this?

Comment: @YashChandra It's a standard partial order on $T_0$ spaces, called the specialisation partial order. So it's an old idea.

Comment: Why "each  minimal element is an open set"? I'can't prove it. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesChan, each minimal set is the insersection of all the open sets that contain it, and these are finitely many.

Comment: I have known why, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by induction on the size $n$ of the space $X$.
The claim is clearly true for $n=1$.
Assume it holds for $n=k$. Let $X=X'\cup\{y\}$ be a $T_0$ space of size $k+1$, where $y\notin X'$.  Then the subspace $X'$ of size $k$ is again a $T_0$ space, so it has an open set $\{x\}$. Now this set is either open in $X$, or it is the intersection of $X'$ with the open set $\{x,y\}$. What can you say about neighborhoods around $y$ using the $T_0$ property?

Comment: If ${x,y}$ is open, then how to use the $T_0$ property about neighborhoods around $y$? Thanks.

Comment: @JamesChan: Either $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ disjoint from $y$ or $y$ has a neighborhood $V$ disjoint from $x$. Either way, the intersection of this neighborhood with $\{x,y\}$ is an open set with a single element.